# FileZilla FTP hanging on "waiting for welcome message" when trying to connect

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ftp, sftp

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and when trying to connect to my server using FTP I get the following hang:

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.2.1:80...  
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message... 
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity 
Error: Could not connect to server
```

What is stopping FileZilla from connecting?

1. I have tried changing the Protocol: FTP / SFTP
2. I have tried changing the Log on type: Current setting is set to Normal
3. I have tried changing the transfer mode: Active / Passive
4. I have tried changing the server type: Current setting is Default (autodetect)

I am not sure what else to check?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Is there a command I can run from the terminal which will let me know what port my FTP server is running on?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that there is FTP server running on the port 80?

Comment: @Jakuje I believe that the FTP server is running on the port 80, but now that you ask I am not sure how to check that?  What is the best way to check to see if my FTP server is running on port 80?

Comment: If it is running there, you probably installed some FTP server, configured and started it there. If not, then it is not running there.

Comment: @Jakuje  I'm sorry I should have been more specific, what I meant to ask was, is there a command I can run from the terminal which will let me know what port  my FTP server is running on?